# How to display double values with two decimals instead of one zero decimal

Tags: android, arrays, double

I want to display two decimals and display in more appropriate way the values without brackets

```
ScanRecord scanRecord = result.getScanRecord();

assert scanRecord != null;
byte[] puckData = scanRecord.getManufacturerSpecificData(0x0590);
assert puckData != null;

double lightValue = Double.parseDouble(
               Arrays.toString(new byte[]{puckData[0]}).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
double tempValue = Double.parseDouble(
               Arrays.toString(new byte[]{puckData[1]}).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
double batteryValue = Double.parseDouble(
               Arrays.toString(new byte[]{puckData[2]}).replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    double lightValue = .0;
    DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00");      
    System.out.println(df.format(lightValue));
```

it will print 0.00

Comment: The value I get from byte array is .0 what can I do to get the whole double value and then format it? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(".##");
Log.d("","kilobytes (DecimalFormat) : " + df.format(123.678));
```

It will return: **123.68**